# Expressively select rows in a data.table which match rows from another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Given two data tables (`tbl_A` and `tbl_B`), I would like to select all the rows in the `tbl_A` which have matching rows in `tbl_B`, and **I would like the code to be expressive**.  If the `%in%` operator were defined for data.tables, something like this would be be ideal:

```
subset <- tbl_A[tbl_A %in% tbl_B]
```

I can think of many ways to accomplish what I want such as:

```
# double negation (set differences)
subset <- tbl_A[!tbl_A[!tbl_B,1,keyby=a]]

# nomatch with keyby and this annoying `[,V1:=NULL]` bit
subset <- tbl_B[,1,keyby=.(a=x)][,V1:=NULL][tbl_A,nomatch=0L]

# nomatch with !duplicated() and setnames()
subset <- tbl_B[!duplicated(tbl_B),.(x)][tbl_A,nomatch=0L]; setnames(subset,"x","a")

# nomatch with !unique() and setnames()
subset <- unique(tbl_B)[,.(x)][tbl_A,nomatch=0L]; setnames(subset,"x","a")

# use of a temporary variable (Thanks @Frank)
subset <- tbl_A[, found := FALSE][tbl_B, found := TRUE][(found)][,found:=NULL][]
```

but each expression is difficult to read and it's not obvious at first glance what the code is doing.  Is there a more idiomatic / expressive way of accomplishing this task?

For purposes of example, here are some toy data.tables:

```
# toy tables
tbl_A  <- data.table(a=letters[1:5],
                     b=1:5,
                     c=rnorm(5))
tbl_B  <- data.table(x=letters[3:7],
                     y=13:17,
                     z=rnorm(5))
# both tables might have multiple rows with the same key fields.  
tbl_A <- rbind(tbl_A,tbl_A)
tbl_B <- rbind(tbl_B,tbl_B)
setkey(tbl_A,a)
setkey(tbl_B,x)
```

and an expected result containing the rows in `tbl_A` which match at least one row in `tbl_B`:

```
   a b          c
1: c 3 -0.5403072
2: c 3 -0.5403072
3: d 4 -1.3353621
4: d 4 -1.3353621
5: e 5  1.1811730
6: e 5  1.1811730
```

Comment: `tbl_A[, found := FALSE][tbl_B, found := TRUE]` ? Btw, open issue/request for that %in% operator: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2279

Comment: it sounds like you want a semi join operator?

Comment: Yes, Precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Adding 2 more options

```
tbl_A[fintersect(tbl_A[,.(a)], tbl_B[,.(a=x)])]
```

and

```
tbl_A[unique(tbl_A[tbl_B, nomatch=0L, which=TRUE])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how expressive it is (apologies if not) but this seems to work:

```
tbl_A[,.(a,b,c,any(a == tbl_B[,x])), by = a][V4==TRUE,.(a,b,c)]
```

I'm sure it can be improved - I only found out about any() yesterday and still testing it :)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Thanks for the response, but I wouldn't particularly call this expressive (not easy to understand with just a glance) and probably not particularly fast because it doesn't take advantage of the keys.  Also, for tables with 100's of columns and multiple keys, it would require a lot of typing...

Comment: Hey Jthorpe. Thanks for the welcome and feedback. You're right, even though it could be reduced to `tbl_A[,.(a,b,c,any(a == tbl_B[,x])), by = a][V4==TRUE]` it still doesn't take advantage of the keys. As for expressive - I had to google it, still loads to learn for me...